# Is this the best way to convert List<T> from models to ObservableCollection<T> in views?

Tags: c#, mvvm, generics, observablecollection

In **MVVM** development I am constantly converting **`List<T>`** from my **models** to **`ObservableCollection<T>`** for my **views**.

I **looked around in .NET** for a way to succinctly do this e.g. such as `.ToList<>` or `.ToArray<>` or `.ToDictionary<>` but couldn't find anything similar for **ObservableCollection**.

Therefore I made the following extention method **`ConvertToObservableCollection<T>()`**.

**Is there a better way to convert `List<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>`, or does every MVVM developer end up writing this extension method at some point?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestObser228342
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<string> names = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
            ObservableCollection<string> ocNames = 
                names.ConvertToObservableCollection<string>();
            ocNames.ToList().ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));

            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Smith" },
                new Customer { FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Adams" },
                new Customer { FirstName = "Collin", LastName = "Rollins" }
            };
            ObservableCollection<Customer> ocCustomers = 
                customers.ConvertToObservableCollection<Customer>();
            ocCustomers.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c));
        }
    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<T> ConvertToObservableCollection<T>
            (this List<T> items)
        {
            ObservableCollection<T> oc = new ObservableCollection<T>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                oc.Add(item);
            }
            return oc;
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Minor comment:  you could name your method `ToObservableCollection` to go along with the theme of `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc.

Comment: Also, does it make sense for your method to extend `List`, or would it be more reasonable/generic for it to extend `Collection` or `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you use the appropriate constructor of [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737.aspx)?

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> ocCustomers = 
         new ObservableCollection<Customer>(customers);
```

Comment: I just wanted to ask him, why he does not use this constructor ^^

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work in silverlight, at least not in version 3.

Comment: here's a short lambda syntax for silverlight: names.ForEach(x => onames.Add(x)), full example: http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=217

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable with ObservableCollection constructor works in Silverlight 4 too.

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper ?

http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays

Answer (score 0):

your solution seems way to complicated...maybe mine is too simple..this is an extension method I wrote to convert my nettiers collections to observable collections...its in vb.net... but you'll get the gist...

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [ToObservableCollection](Of T)(ByVal list As IEnumerable(Of T)) As ObservableCollection(Of T)
        Dim collection As New ObservableCollection(Of T)

        For Each l As T In list
            collection.Add(l)
        Next

        Return collection
    End Function
```

here is the converted C#

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]
public ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    
    foreach (T l in list) {
        collection.Add(l);
    }
    
    return collection;
}
```

I suppose to you could use a lambda, but I dont understand them, so I avoid them.

Comment: doh...maybe I got lost in your other code, I see it looks like you are already doing this...but once you have it in a root infrastructure class you dont have to write it ever again...